# D3 chart is duplicating on React.js component

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

This is on a react application, what might be going wrong? A new svg is appended everytime, instead of the one that exists updating...
I'm not sure what other details I should add, I already included all the info that you may need to help me, please let me know if there's anything else I should add. Thank you.
[image]

This is my component, I'm passing the data through props.

```
export const FourDirectionsTimeChart = ({data}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const width = document.getElementById("container").clientWidth;
        const height = document.getElementById("container").clientHeight;
        const R = (width + height) / 8;
        const CX = width / 2;
        const CY = height / 2;
        const smallR = R * 0.1;
        const circleColor = "bisque";
        const itemColor = "#3F4200";

        let svg = d3.select("#container")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
            .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)

        let mainCircle = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("fill", circleColor)
            .attr("r", R)
            .attr("cx", CX)
            .attr("cy", CY);

        let centerCircle = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("fill", "white")
            .attr("r", smallR)
            .attr("cx", CX)
            .attr("cy", CY);

        const timePercentage = (time) => {
            const percentage = (time * 100 / 23) / 100;
            return percentage;
        };
        function timeToRadius(time) {
            return (smallR + timePercentage(time) * (R - smallR))
        }

        // Times concentric circles ---
        for (let i = 0; i <= 23; i += 4) {
            svg.append("circle")
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("cx", CX)
                .attr("cy", CY)
                .attr("stroke-dasharray", "4 20")
                .attr("stroke", "gray")
                .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                .attr("r", timeToRadius(i))
        }

        // Cardinal points ---
        const textTime = 25;
        const fontSize = R * 0.25;
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("dx", getPosition(0, textTime).x)
            .attr("dy", getPosition(0, textTime).y)
            .text("N")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("font-size", fontSize)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-family", "serif")
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("dx", getPosition(180, textTime).x)
            .attr("dy", getPosition(180, textTime).y)
            .text("S")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("font-size", fontSize)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-family", "serif")
            .attr("alignment-baseline", "hanging")
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("dx", getPosition(-90, textTime).x)
            .attr("dy", getPosition(-90, textTime).y)
            .text("E")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("font-size", fontSize)
            .attr("text-anchor", "start")
            .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
            .style("font-family", "serif");
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("dx", getPosition(90, textTime).x)
            .attr("dy", getPosition(90, textTime).y)
            .text("O")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("font-size", fontSize)
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
            .style("font-family", "serif")

        // Ships positions --- 
        function getPosition(degrees, time) {
            const getRadians = (degrees) => degrees * Math.PI / 180 + Math.PI / 2;
            let x = (smallR + timePercentage(time) * (R - smallR)) * Math.cos(getRadians(degrees)) + CX;
            let y = (smallR + timePercentage(time) * (R - smallR)) * Math.sin(getRadians(degrees)) * -1 + CY;
            return { x, y };
        }

        // Data mapping ---
        let parsedData = [];
        (() => {
            data?.forEach((x) => {
                parsedData.push({
                    id: x.Patente,
                    course: x.Rumbo,
                    speed: x.Velocidad,
                    time: new Date(x.Fecha_gps).getHours()
                })
            });

            let position;
            parsedData.map(d => {
                position = getPosition(d.course, d.time);
                svg.append("circle")
                    .attr("fill", () => {
                        if (d.speed == 0) return "brown";
                        else return "brown";
                    })
                    .attr("r", R * 0.015)
                    .attr("cx", position.x)
                    .attr("cy", position.y)
                    .attr("opacity", 0.4);
            });
        })();

    }, [data]);

    return (
        <div id="container" style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}></div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you think the line `let svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")` does? It selects the element with ID `"container"` and appends a new SVG element to it.

You can essentially do one of two things:

1. Select and [remove](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/#selection_remove) all existing SVG elements in the container and then draw the chart from scratch on update: `d3.select("#container svg").remove()`, then `d3.select("#container").append("svg")`;
2. Split the initialization (append svg, set size, draw axes) logic from the logic that might need to be run multiple times (update the values) and make sure to call only the second part on update. This is more complex, but also efficient, especially in an already DOM-heavy ecosystem like React.

---

I've taken your code and added an example of how I would implement the second way below:

Note that to access `R`, `smallR`, etc, I've had to divide the initialization logic over two `useEffect` hooks.

```js
const {
  useEffect,
  useState
} = React;

const FourDirectionsTimeChart = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [constants, setConstants] = useState({});

  // Initialization logic, run only once
  useEffect(() => {
    const width = document.getElementById("container").clientWidth;
    const height = document.getElementById("container").clientHeight;
    const R = (width + height) / 8;
    const CX = width / 2;
    const CY = height / 2;
    const smallR = R * 0.1;

    setConstants({
      R,
      CX,
      CY,
      smallR
    });

    const circleColor = "bisque";
    const itemColor = "#3F4200";

    const svg = d3.select("#container")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
      .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

    const mainCircle = svg.append("circle")
      .attr('id', 'mainCircle')
      .attr("fill", circleColor);

    const centerCircle = svg.append("circle")
      .attr('id', 'innerCircle')
      .attr("fill", "white");

    // Times concentric circles ---
    for (let i = 0; i <= 23; i += 4) {
      svg.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "concentric")
        .datum(i)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", "4 20")
        .attr("stroke", "gray")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1);
    }

    // Cardinal points ---
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("id", "N")
      .text("N")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-family", "serif")
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("id", "S")
      .text("S")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-family", "serif")
      .attr("alignment-baseline", "hanging")
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("id", "E")
      .text("E")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
      .style("font-family", "serif");
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("id", "O")
      .text("O")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
      .style("font-family", "serif")
  }, []);

  // Drawing logic, run whenever `constants` changes (which is only once)
  useEffect(() => {
    const { R, smallR, CX, CY } = constants;
    const textTime = 25;
    const fontSize = R * 0.25;

    const svg = d3.select("#container svg");

    const mainCircle = svg.select("#mainCircle")
      .attr("r", R)
      .attr("cx", CX)
      .attr("cy", CY);

    const centerCircle = svg.select("#innerCircle")
      .attr("r", smallR)
      .attr("cx", CX)
      .attr("cy", CY);

    // Times concentric circles ---
    function timeToRadius(time) {
      return (smallR + timePercentage(time) * (R - smallR));
    }

    svg.selectAll(".concentric")
      .attr("cx", CX)
      .attr("cy", CY)
      .attr("r", d => timeToRadius(d))

    // Cardinal points ---
    svg.select("text#N")
      .attr("font-size", fontSize)
      .attr("dx", getPosition(0, textTime).x)
      .attr("dy", getPosition(0, textTime).y);
    svg.select("text#S")
      .attr("font-size", fontSize)
      .attr("dx", getPosition(180, textTime).x)
      .attr("dy", getPosition(180, textTime).y);
    svg.select("text#E")
      .attr("font-size", fontSize)
      .attr("dx", getPosition(-90, textTime).x)
      .attr("dy", getPosition(-90, textTime).y);
    svg.select("text#O")
      .attr("font-size", fontSize)
      .attr("dx", getPosition(90, textTime).x)
      .attr("dy", getPosition(90, textTime).y);
  }, [constants]);

  const timePercentage = (time) => {
    const percentage = (time * 100 / 23) / 100;
    return percentage;
  };

  function timeToRadius(time) {
    const {
      smallR,
      R
    } = constants;
    return (smallR + timePercentage(time) * (R - smallR));
  }

  const getRadians = (degrees) => degrees * Math.PI / 180 + Math.PI / 2;

  function getPosition(degrees, time) {
    const {
      smallR,
      R,
      CX,
      CY
    } = constants;
    const x = (smallR + timePercentage(time) * (R - smallR)) * Math.cos(getRadians(degrees)) + CX;
    const y = (smallR + timePercentage(time) * (R - smallR)) * Math.sin(getRadians(degrees)) * -1 + CY;
    return {
      x,
      y
    };
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3.select('#container svg');

    // Data mapping ---
    let position;
    
    const points = svg.selectAll('.point').data(data);
    
    // Remove old points
    points.exit().remove();
    
    // Append and set constants only for new points
    points
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'point')
      .attr("r", 15)
      .attr("opacity", 0.4)
    
      // Then, take both the new and the updated points
      .merge(points)
      .attr("cx", d => getPosition(d.course, d.time).x)
      .attr("cy", d => getPosition(d.course, d.time).y)
      .attr("fill", d => d.speed === 0 ? "brown" : "red");
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let i = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      setData(i % 2 === 0 ? data1 : data2);
      i++;
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return ( <
    div id = "container"
    style = {
      {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
      }
    } > < /div>
  )
}

const data1 = [{
  id: 100,
  course: 35,
  speed: 0,
  time: 5
}];

const data2 = [{
  id: 101,
  course: 80,
  speed: 25,
  time: 12
}, {
  id: 102,
  course: 256,
  speed: 0,
  time: 15
}];

ReactDOM.render( <
  FourDirectionsTimeChart / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"></div>
```

Comment: Would you do #2 in two separate useEffect? One that updates when data updates, and another one with an empty dependency array?

Comment: Yes, that would be good. Note that you should have the empty one before the one where data updates, and you could potentially add a third one if you need to respond to window resize events for example.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot can you please give an example of your solution in a real project(snippet) :) thanks

Comment: @Denis, I've added an example based on the original question

Comment: @RubenHelsloot, I know that is not correct to ask about the specific opinion of the specific user, but I my opinion, your point of view will help not just me but everyone. In this sense can you please look at the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73933937/d3-and-react-grid-layout

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, he

Also, check if you have [StrictMode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode) enabled, as it renders the wrapped tree twice,