# D3 and react-grid-layout

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js, responsive, grid-layout

I have a React and d3 component that is unable to resize properly. I've based it on [these](https://codesandbox.io/s/182lw48lo7) [examples](https://codesandbox.io/s/dg3tj).

```js
const {
  useState,
  useRef,
  useEffect
} = React;
const { Responsive: ResponsiveGridLayout } = ReactGridLayout;

const Chart = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [data] = useState([35, 78, 38, 35, 78, 38, 35, 78, 38, 35, 78, 38]);
  const svgRef = useRef();
  const [h, setHeight] = useState(100);
  const [w, setWidth] = useState(500);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    //setting up svg
    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current)
      .attr('width', '99%')
      .attr('height', '20%')
      .style('background', '#d3d3d4')
      .style('margin-left', '10px')
      .style('margin-top', '10px')
      .style('overflow', 'visible')

    //setting up scaling
    const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, data.length - 1])
      .range([0, w]);
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, h])
      .range([h, 0]);
    const generateScaledLine = d3.line()
      .x((d, i) => xScale(i))
      .y(yScale)
      .curve(d3.curveCardinal)
    //setting up axis
    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
      .ticks(data.length)
      .tickFormat(i => i + 1);
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
      .ticks(5);
    svg.append('g')
      .call(xAxis)
      .attr('transform', `translate(0 , ${h})`);
    svg.append('g')
      .call(yAxis)
    //setting up the data for the svg 
    svg.selectAll('.line')
      .data([data])
      .join('path')
      .attr('d', d => generateScaledLine(d))
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('stroke', 'black');
  }, [data, w]);

  console.log(props.width);
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <svg ref={svgRef}></svg>
    </div>
  );
});

function Content({ width }) {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [layouts, setLayouts] = useState({ lg: [] });
  const onLayoutChange = (_, allLayouts) => {
    setLayouts(allLayouts);
  };
  const onRemoveItem = (itemId) => {
    if (itemId === null) {
      console.log("null");
    }
    setItems(items.filter((i) => i !== itemId));
  };
  
  const onAddItem = () => {
    const itemId = Math.max(...items, 0) + 1;
    setItems([...items, itemId]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ResponsiveGridLayout
        draggableHandle=".drag-handle"
        className="layout"
        layouts={layouts}
        breakpoints={{ lg: 500, md: 400, sm: 300, xs: 200 }}
        cols={{ lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 }}
        allowOverlap={false}
        width={width}
        onLayoutChange={(layout, layouts) => onLayoutChange(layout, layouts)}
      >
        {items.map((key) => (
          <div
            key={key}
            data-grid={{ w: 4, h: 1, x: 0, minH: 1, minW: 4, y: 5 }}
          >
            <Chart />
            <button onClick={() => onRemoveItem(key)}>X</button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ResponsiveGridLayout>
      <button onClick={onAddItem}>Add item</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Content width={500} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-grid-layout@1.3.4/dist/react-grid-layout.min.js"></script>

<div id="root" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
```

**Update:**

Hopefully, after the help of [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21061/ian?tab=profile), it was possible to move to the next steps.
Problems at the moment:

1. Cannot resize the height of chart
2. Chart are duplicated even if I removed the previous one(based on [D3 chart is duplicating on React.js component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70252175/d3-chart-is-duplicating-on-react-js-component/70252250?noredirect=1#comment130583695_70252250))

Live: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-bird-uwo1j9?file=/src/components/LineCharts.js

**Update2:**

Live: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-bird-uwo1j9?file=/src/components/LineCharts.js

Based on https://codesandbox.io/s/ape-bm-charts-vsndr
Us result not able to display datetime and line on chart

Comment: I have changed your code to be a runnable snippet, but you need to make your question clearer. Do you want help with making the charts resizable or do you want help with redrawing the charts? Make your question more focused so other people with the same question can benefit from it as well.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback. It would be beneficial if you could answer both questions, but it is apt for you to respond to one of them